# Can we prove that every ordered space is normal without choice?

Tags: general-topology, set-theory, axiom-of-choice

In ZFC, every linear ordered space with respect to the order topology is completely normal. I saw the [this proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/322974/53976) and proof of this statement in the book "Counterexamples of topology" (Example 39). But as I have seen every proof of this statement uses choice. Even if (as I know) the proof of "Every linear continuum is normal" uses the axiom of choice.

So I think that choice is essential to prove this statement. That is true? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot do that without the axiom of choice. See the following paper by van Douwen:

> Eric K. van Douwen, **"[Horrors of Topology Without AC: A Nonnormal Orderable Space](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1985-095-01/S0002-9939-1985-0796455-5/)"**. *Proceedings of the American Mathematical Society* Vol. **95**, No. 1 (Sep., 1985), pp. 101-105

And also related is this paper by Krom:

> Melven Krom , **"[A linearly ordered topological space that is not normal](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ndjfl/1093636518)"**. *Notre Dame J. Formal Logic* Volume **27**, Number 1 (1986), 12-13.

Comment: @Arthur: Thanks!