# Total order and its order topology

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, uniform-spaces, order-topology

I noticed that the natural order of the Reals alone, being complete ( satisfying LUB ) ,  is able to prove that the induced order topology is complete ( every Cauchy sequence converges ).     We are able to talk about completeness of such topology, because it ends up being uniformizable ( even more, it is metrizable ).

Now, i'm asking myself if any total order that is complete can induce a topology that is at least [uniformizable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_space), so that it will be able to prove the completeness of its induced uniform structure.

Finally, i'm a real beginner in topology and real analysis, i don't even know if there could be any possible example of a complete order whose induced order topology ( even if uniformizable ) that would be interesting ... I'm crawling in the dark but at the same time just trying to see to what degree of generality things hold.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\langle X,\le\rangle$ be a linear order, and let $\tau$ be the order topology on $X$ induced by $\le$: $\tau$ has as a subbase $\{(\leftarrow,x):x\in X\}\cup\{(x,\to):x\in X\}$. Then the space $\langle X,\tau\rangle$ is $T_5$, i.e., $T_1$ and hereditarily normal; you can find proofs [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/322683/why-are-ordered-spaces-normal-collecting-proofs). In particular, $X$ is completely regular and [therefore uniformizable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_space#Uniformizable_spaces). None of this requires that the order be complete.

If the order is complete, including endpoints, then $X$ is compact; if it’s complete in the weaker sense that every set bounded above has a supremum, then it need not be compact, since it need not have endpoints, but it satisfies a Heine-Borel theorem: a subset of $X$ is compact if and only if it’s closed and bounded. In particular, $X$ is locally compact, so it satisfies the Baire category theorem, just as if it were a complete metric space.

Comment: Thanks for that. Do you know any example of another uniform structure ( metric space or not ) , unrelated to the reals , that is complete and induced by some natural order or perhaps the reals is the only example? Is it more of a characteristic of the reals and i shouldn't be looking elsewhere ? Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: @nerdy: Take any compact linearly ordered space: since it’s compact and Hausdorff, it has a unique uniformity, which by compactness is necessarily complete. There are many compact linearly ordered spaces that have nothing to do with the reals, e.g., $\omega_1+1$ in its natural order, where $\omega_1$ is the first uncountable ordinal.

Comment: Just to confirm. So every linearly ordered set that is dedekind complete ( the weaker kind of completeness ) induces an order topology is at least locally compact , correct ?

Comment: @nerdy: Yes, that’s correct.