# Order topology is regular and not normal

Tags: general-topology

[π-Base](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces?q=LOTS%2B%7ENormal) shows that linear order topology is not normal. But I remember in class the prof said order topology is normal.

If $X$ is a set with linear order $<$, define a topology on X by letting $\{(a,b):a<b\}$ be a basis (where $(a,b)=\{x∈X:a<x<b\}$).

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/322683/why-are-ordered-spaces-normal-collecting-proofs. It is even hereditarily normal.

Comment: That entry is flat wrong. A LOTS (linearly ordered topological space with the order topology) is even hereditarily [collectionwise normal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collectionwise_normal_space), which is about as strong a normality property as you can get.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments note, every LOTS is normal. It's possible the pi-Base had such an error in 2015, but [today it knows better](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces?q=LOTS%2B%7ENormal).