# Cheap proof that the Sorgenfrey line is normal?

Tags: general-topology, separation-axioms, sorgenfrey-line

It is very easy to prove that the Sorgenfrey line is completely regular:

> To separate a point $x$ from a closed set $F$, note that there is an interval $[x,y)$ disjoint from $F$ and observe that the characteristic function of $[x,y)$ is continuous because the half-open intervals generating the topology are clopen.

The proof of normality seems considerably harder.  The argument I found in several books proceeds in two steps:

1. Show that the Sorgenfrey line is Lindelöf.
2. Show that a regular Lindelöf space is normal.

Both these steps are much harder than the above argument. Putting those two arguments together, one obtains something like the argument for point H in Dan Ma's [a note on the sorgenfrey line](https://dantopology.wordpress.com/2009/09/27/a-note-on-the-sorgenfrey-line/).

> Is there a shortcut that is simpler than putting these two arguments together?

Answer (score 27):

Suppose $A,B$ are disjoint closed sets in the Sorgenfrey line. We have to find open sets $U,V$ such that $A\subseteq U,\ B\subseteq V,$ and $U\cap V=\emptyset.$

For each $a\in A$ choose $a'\gt a,$ $\ [a,a')\cap B=\emptyset$; then $U=\bigcup\limits_{a\in A}[a,a')$ is an open set containing $A.$

For each $b\in B$ choose $b'\gt b,$ $\ [b,b')\cap A=\emptyset$; then $V=\bigcup_\limits{b\in B}[b,b')$ is an open set containing $B.$

To show that $U\cap V=\emptyset,$ it suffices to show that $[a,a')\cap[b,b')=\emptyset$ for all $a\in A,\ b\in B.$ Suppose $a\in A,\ b\in B,$ and assume without loss of generality that $a\lt b.$ Since $[a,a')\cap B=\emptyset,$ it follows that $b\ge a'$ and so $[a,a')\cap[b,b')=\emptyset.$

Comment: Why can you choose the $a's$ and $b's$ like that?

Comment: Given $a\in A$, why can I choose $a'\gt a$ with $[a,a')\cap B=\emptyset$? Well, $A$ and $B$ are disjoint, and $a\in A$, so $a\notin B$. Since $B$ is closed and $a\notin B$, some neighborhood of $a$ is disjoint from $B$. In the Sorgenfrey topology, the neighborhoods of $a$ have a base consisting of sets of the form $[a,a')$. Okay?

Answer (score 8):

That argument is as easy as any that I know, and its second part is an important result in its own right. An alternative is to prove that [every linearly ordered topological space is hereditarily normal](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/322974/12042) and then show that the Sorgenfrey line is a subspace of a linearly ordered space. The second step is easy. Let $X=\Bbb R\times\{0,1\}$ ordered lexicographically: $\langle x,i\rangle\preceq\langle y,j\rangle$ if and only if $x<y$, or $x=y$ and $i\le j$. Give $X$ the order topology generated by $\preceq$, and let $Y$ be the subspace $\Bbb R\times\{1\}$ with the topology that it inherits from $X$. If $\Bbb S$ denotes the Sorgenfrey line, the map

$$f:\Bbb S\to Y:x\mapsto\langle x,1\rangle$$

is easily seen to be a homeomorphism. $Y$ is normal as a subspace of the linearly ordered space $X$, so $\Bbb S$ is normal.