# Show that $\mathbb{Q}$ with the topology induced by the Sorgenfrey line is normal

Tags: general-topology

Show that $\mathbb{Q}$ with the topology induced by the Sorgenfrey line is normal.

Here, the Sorgenfrey line is the line with the topology whose basis are formed as:

$$\{[a,b) : a < b \}$$

I know that, assuming that it is not normal, I have to show that for any two closed sets, every pair of open sets containing each one of them has to be non trivial. How to do this?

Comment: The answers on [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1416757/169789) might be helpful.

Comment: @Leonardo: Specifically, [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/322974/12042) has what you need in a very general form.