# Why is Sorgenfrey Line normal?

Tags: general-topology

I'm currently learning about normal spaces and I read the proof that the Sorgenfrey line is normal. The main idea was that for every two sets we can find an open set for each point such that the intersection of all the sets is empty, [here is a more detailed proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1416757/cheap-proof-that-the-sorgenfrey-line-is-normal). My question is - how can we separate the set Q of all rational numbers in R from the set P of all irrational numbers in R? Both Q and P are dense in R so shouldn't it be impossible to separate them from each other?

Comment: The Sorgenfrey line is (hereditarily) normal because it's monotonically normal (from being a GO-space).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Normality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_space#Definitions) only demands that we be able to separate arbitrary disjoint **closed** sets - since $\mathbb{Q}$ is neither closed nor open in the Sorgenfrey line (or in the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$ for that matter), our inability to separate the rationals and the irrationals by closed neighborhoods is irrelevant.

- It may not be obvious at first that $\mathbb{Q}$ is neither closed nor open in the Sorgenfrey topology. If that's the case, this is a good exercise. HINT: can you show that neither the rationals nor the irrationals contain an interval of the form $[a,b)$ with $a<b$? If so, do you see why this means that neither the rationals nor the irrationals are open in the Sorgenfrey sense?

Comment: Note for the op: if $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{P}$ are dense, then they are not closed. Since the sets are complementary they are neither open.