# Proof Verification Half Open Intervals are Normal Topological Spaces

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, separation-axioms

This is the question I am attempting: Show that the real line with the topology generated by the collection of half-open
intervals $[a, b) = \{x \mid a \leq x < b \}$ is normal topological space.

Here is my attempt at the question. My proof seems too simple so I am guessing that I missed something. Any help is appreciated.

Proof: Here the basis elements of this topology are half-open intervals. So any open set must be some combination of those basis elements. So any open set $U$ has the following form.
$$
U = \cdots \cup [a_i, b_i) \cup [a_{i+1}, b_{i+1}) \cup \cdots
$$

So, the closed set $C = X \setminus U$ would have the form
$$
C = \cdots \cup [b_i, a_{i+1}) \cup [b_{i+1}, a_{i+2}) \cup \cdots
$$

But notice that this is also a combination of basis elements. So $C$ is also open. This implies that any closed set is also open and vice versa. So if we have two disjoint closed sets $C_1, C_2$, then trivially $C_1, C_2$ are disjoint open neighborhoods containing $C_1, C_2$, meaning that $X$ is indeed a normal topological space.

Comment: Formatting note:  type `\{` to get `{`

Comment: An open set $U$ is a union of countably many disjoint half-open intervals, but not nessarily ordered like $\Bbb N$ or $\Bbb Z.$

Comment: After that, does this answer your question? [Cheap proof that the Sorgenfrey line is normal?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1416757/cheap-proof-that-the-sorgenfrey-line-is-normal)

Comment: @AnneBauval I believe I follow that argument. It seems like it at least follows a similar line of logic as what I did in my proof. To clarify, are you saying that my proof is invalid? I am not sure exactly what you mean when you say that the union of countably many disjoint half-open intervals is not ordered. I would think it is ordered since $\mathbb{R}$ is ordered. Thank you.

Comment: It is ordered, but the order-type is not that of $\Bbb N$ or $\Bbb Z$ as your (therefore invalid) proof suggests and uses with its indexing.