# Is this a normal topology?

Tags: general-topology

Let $\tau$ be the usual topology on $\Bbb R$. I'm studying the following topology on $\Bbb R$:

$$\alpha = \{O \cup U: O \in \tau \text{ and } \Bbb Q \subset \Bbb R \setminus U\}$$

So far, I found that:

- $(\Bbb R,\alpha)$ is regular. Indeed, for $a \in \Bbb R$ and $A = (\Bbb R \setminus O) \cap (\Bbb R \setminus U)$ a closed set for $\alpha$ with $a \notin A$, we have two possibilities: if $a \in \Bbb Q$, then $a \in \Bbb R \setminus U$, so $a \notin \Bbb R \setminus O$, which is closed, so by regularity of $(\Bbb R, \tau)$, there exist disjoint $\tau$-open neighbourhoods $G$ and $H$ for $x$ and $\Bbb R \setminus O$ respectively, but since $\alpha$ is finer than $\tau$, these are in $\alpha$, and $A \subset H$ since $A \subset \Bbb R \setminus O$. If $a \notin \Bbb Q$, then $\{a\}$ is open and so $\{a\}$ and $\Bbb R \setminus \{a\}$ are disjoint $\alpha$-open neighbourhoods of $x$ and $A$.
- $(\Bbb R, \alpha)$ is not separable (since any dense set must contain $\Bbb R \setminus \Bbb Q$)
- $(\Bbb R, \alpha)$ is first countable: if $x \in \Bbb R \setminus \Bbb Q$, $\{\{x\}\}$ is a local base. Otherwise, $\{]x-\frac1n, x+\frac1n[: n \in \Bbb N\}$ is a local base.

I still don't understand this topology well enough. So, **I'm investigating whether it's normal, and if not, whether it's completely regular**. I guess it's not normal because it seems that it has "too many open sets", but I'm not sure how to proceed. Can someone help me figure this out? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has a base of clopen sets, so it’s automatically completely regular; since it’s also $T_1$, it’s actually Tikhonov. But in fact it’s hereditarily normal.

Let

$$X=\{\langle x,n\rangle\in\Bbb R\times\Bbb Z:n=0\text{ or }x\in\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q\}\;,$$

and let $\preceq$ be the lexicographic order on $X$. Endow $X$ with the order topology generated by $\preceq$, i.e., the topology generated by the subbase of sets of the forms $L_x=\{y\in X:y\prec x\}$ and $R_x=\{y\in X:x\prec y\}$ for $x\in X$.) Every space whose topology is generated in this way by a linear order is $T_5$ (i.e., hereditarily normal and $T_1$); there’s a proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/322974/12042).

Let $Y=\Bbb R\times\{0\}$, with the relative topology that it inherits from $X$; $Y$ is $T_4$ (i.e., normal and $T_1$). To complete the proof that $\langle\Bbb R,\alpha\rangle$ is $T_5$, show that it is homeomorphic to $Y$.

This space is called the *Michael line*, after Ernie Michael, who first used it as a counterexample and studied it in some detail; its properties are covered at some length in [Dan Ma’s Topology Blog](https://dantopology.wordpress.com/2012/10/28/michael-line-basics/).

Comment: This is really enlightening. Thank you!

Comment: @François: You’re welcome!