# Showing $\mathbb{R}$ with the standard topology union irrational subsets is normal.

Tags: general-topology

We are given that $\mathcal{T}$ is the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathcal{O}=\{O\in\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}):O=U\cup A, U\in\mathcal{T}, A\subseteq\mathbb{R}\backslash\mathbb{Q}\}$. It can easily be shown that $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{O})$ is a topology. Now we want to show that this space is normal, and as a hint, we are given that every metric space is normal.

So I assume that the idea is to show that $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{O})$ is metrizable, by finding a suitable metric $d$ that induces the same topology $\mathcal{O}$. However, I have no idea where to start to find such a metric. Is this the correct approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That space is the [Michael line](https://dantopology.wordpress.com/2012/10/28/michael-line-basics/). It is **not** metrizable, but it is paracompact and therefore normal. There is a proof of paracompactness at the link, but the result is quite easy using the fact that the usual topology on $\Bbb R$ is paracompact, so it’s worth trying on your own if you’ve done anything with paracompactness.

I gave a very different proof that the Michael line is normal in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2018441/is-this-a-normal-topology/2018486#2018486) to an earlier question.

Comment: I see, thank you! I will search a bit more on paracompact spaces and check your answer. Do you have any idea what the hint might be referring to?

Comment: @DylanZammit: You’re welcome! No, I confess to being quite confused by the hint.

Comment: The space is also [monotonically normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonically_normal_space) and hence hereditarily normal.