# Show that omega_1 is normal?

Tags: general-topology, ordinals

I've already proven the following statement. If $A$ and $B$ are disjoint closed subsets of $\omega_1$, then at least one of them must be bounded. This proof is supposed to be used to prove that $\omega_1$ is normal but I can't figure out how to do that.

I have the following so far:
Take A to be the bounded set. Since A is bounded and closed, it is also compact. We have already shown that $\omega_1$ is regular.

Comment: What’s definition of $\omega_1$?

Comment: @user264745 Omega_1 is the first/smallest uncountable ordinal

Comment: I think the request was for you to explain the topology on $\omega_1$.

Comment: I’m Sorry. I don’t known what ordinal is. I just [googled](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjizvGk_tL3AhWd7XMBHblCB1MQFnoECA0QAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FFirst_uncountable_ordinal&usg=AOvVaw0D6xx7-7rcpV9rPatfWjpX) it. $\omega_1$ is a well ordered set. You may known, every well ordered set is normal in order topology fact or just check theorem 32.4 of Munkres’ topology.

Comment: @user264745 it would be the order topology, I believe.

Comment: If you’re using order topology and you want to show regular($T_1$ and $T_3$), you can prove a stronger result. Link: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4439856/861687.

Comment: @user264745 We are showing normal, not regular.

Comment: @Nicole Yeah. I know that. You can also prove that for normal space. Did my previous of previous comment answer your question?